# How to set password or authentication for .mdf(service based database) file in vs2010?

Tags: c#, sql-server-express, mdf

I am developing a stand alone windows application in c#
I am using service based database.

Can anyone tell me how to protect .mdf database from copying or attaching to sql server management studio without password from Client's machine ??

Is there any way to set Sql authentication for .mdf file ?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the data folder any one can take database(.mdf file).
And in import into their own sqlserver.
We want to protect data.
If some body take our database (.mdf file) then it can not import it into their own system.

Answer (score 0):

No, is not possible.

If you want to prevent your users from using the database directly then you must host the database yourself, which implies making your application a Web service rather that a standalone Windows app.

Do not fall for various scams that pretend they offer a solution for this problem. Is all snake oil.

Comment: Then how the companies are deliver their software with database?

Comment: My aim is to deliver a software with oneclick installation(software+sql server)

Answer (score 0):

just use SQL Server instead of SQL Express 
add your SQL database file to a installed SQL server Machine And Change Connection string to connect to it via SQL server 
then you can set password on your database in SQL server